# Is quantile regression model a parametric approach?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, quantile-regression, semiparametric

Is quantile regression a parametric regression or it is semiparametric? If it is parametric then what are its assumptions and if semiparametric then how?

Comment: You need to show your definitions; these terms aren't all used in exactly the same way across statistical science. It's definitely focused on estimating parameters. That makes it parametric in one precise sense. It has weaker assumptions (ideal conditions) than say linear regression postulating Gaussian (normal) errors. That tempts many to call it something else, say semi-parametric. What hinges on the categorisation, which arguably isn't needed or helpful?

Comment: @Nick I find it helpful to distinguish *parameters* (which are used to specify possible states of nature in a statistical model) from *properties* (which are numerical functions of those states of nature).  Many, if not most, non-parametric models are capable of estimating properties, such as the median or specified percentile of a distribution. Quantile regression is usually conducted nonparametrically--that is, little is assumed about the conditional distributions--but it aims to estimate quantiles of those distributions.

Comment: Is it tautological to say that parameters are what are estimated directly? So, if I fit a named distribution with various parameters, the fit implies various percentiles, and so forth.